# Constraint, based on join with another table

Tags: postgresql

I have table `tariffs`, with two columns: `(tariff_id, reception)`

I have table `users`, with two columns: `(user_id, reception)`

And I have table `users_tariffs` with two columns: `(user_id, tariff_id)`.

I want to prevent situation when tariff from one reception is assigned to user from another reception. How can I do that?

E.G

Users:

```
user_id | reception
Putin   | Russia
Trump   | USA
```

Tariffs:

```
tariff_id | reception
cheap     | USA
expensive | Russia
```

Wrong situation at users_tariffs, because Cheap tariff is for USA only:

```
user_id | tariff_id
Putin   | Cheap
```

Comment: Reception is like contry. People from Europe can't get assigned tariff from Usa.

Comment: What functional dependencies do you have? `(user, reception) -> tariff`, `(tariff, reception) -> user` and `(user, tariff) -> reception`? All three? Any subset? What is many-to-many? What is one-to-many? What is one-to-one? Which of them are must-exist (minimum 1 entry)? Which are may have (zero or more)? What are your primary keys? What is unique? What are your foreign keys?

Comment: User_id is unique, tariff_id is unique, all values are not null

Comment: Dont really understand what `functional dependencies` are, but any user can have any tariff from those, that asssigned to his reception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145741/discussion-between-flutter-and-denis-matafonov).

Comment: Added **EDIT A, TRIGGER ALTERNATIVE** as second alternative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1: FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS**

I am assuming the following table definitions.
In particular, the composite key in `user_tariffs` makes this a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `tariffs`.

```
CREATE TABLE tariffs (tariff_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
                      reception text NOT NULL);  
CREATE TABLE users (user_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
                    reception text NOT NULL);  
CREATE TABLE user_tariffs (tariff_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES tariffs (tariff_id),  
                           user_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),  
                           PRIMARY KEY (tariff_id, user_id));
```

You probably need a combination of all three columns somewhere, so let's create this:

```
ALTER TABLE user_tariffs ADD COLUMN reception text;  
UPDATE user_tariffs a  
SET reception = b.reception  
FROM (SELECT * FROM tariffs) b  
WHERE a.tariff_id = b.tariff_id;  
ALTER TABLE user_tariffs ALTER COLUMN reception SET NOT NULL;
```

Now we can use FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES `(user_id, reception)` into `users`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tariffs (tariff_id, reception);  
ALTER TABLE user_tariffs ADD FOREIGN KEY (tariff_id, reception)  
                      REFERENCES tariffs (tariff_id, reception);
```

In addition, we can use FK REFs `(tariff_id, reception)` into `tariffs`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON users (user_id, reception);  
ALTER TABLE user_tariffs ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id, reception) 
                        REFERENCES users (user_id, reception);
```

Populate with data:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'cheap'), (2, 'expensive');
INSERT INTO tariffs VALUES (1, 'cheap'), (2, 'expensive');
```

Now assume we have the following data `(user_id, tariff_id)` to insert:

```
WITH data (user_id, tariff_id) 
       AS (VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1)),   -- here is your application data
     datas (user_id, tariff_id, reception) 
       AS (SELECT user_id, 
                  tariff_id, 
                  (SELECT u.reception  -- reception calculated by user
                   FROM users u 
                   WHERE u.user_id = d.user_id)  
           FROM data d) 
INSERT INTO user_tariffs SELECT * FROM datas ;
```

Then you cannot insert the data, because you can only add `(1, 1)` or `(2, 2)` with the same `reception`, but not `(1, 2)` or `(2, 1)` with different `reception`'s. The error message is:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "user_tariffs" violates foreign key constraint "user_tariffs_user_id_fkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, reception)=(2, cheap) is not present in table "users".
```

But you can insert with `data AS VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2)`.
I think the FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT solution is to be preferred.

Please describe your `functional dependencies`, if you want better table designs.

**SOLUTION 2: TRIGGER**

```
-- DROP TABLE user_tariffs CASCADE;  
-- DROP TABLE users CASCADE;  
-- DROP TABLE tariffs CASCADE;  
CREATE TABLE tariffs (tariff_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
                      reception text NOT NULL);  
CREATE TABLE users (user_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
                    reception text NOT NULL);  
CREATE TABLE user_tariffs (tariff_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES tariffs (tariff_id),  
                           user_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),  
                           PRIMARY KEY (tariff_id, user_id));  
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'cheap'), (2, 'expensive');  
INSERT INTO tariffs VALUES (1, 'cheap'), (2, 'expensive');  
-- table user_tariffs (user_id, tariff_id) only, without reception column.
```

Create a function with return type trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_reception()  
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE valid boolean := false;
BEGIN 
SELECT (SELECT u.reception FROM users u WHERE u.user_id = NEW.user_id) 
     = (SELECT t.reception FROM tariffs t WHERE t.tariff_id = NEW.tariff_id) 
INTO valid FROM user_tariffs ;
IF valid = false  
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION '(user, tariff, reception) invalid.';  
END IF;  
RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

and register it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reception_trigger  
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON user_tariffs  
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_reception();
```

Now try to insert (1, 2), which would be (cheap, expensive) and is not allowed:

```
INSERT INTO user_tariffs VALUES (1, 2);
ERROR:  (user, tariff, reception) invalid.
KONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_reception() line 7 at RAISE
```

But we can insert (1, 1), which is (cheap, cheap) without problem:

```
INSERT INTO user_tariffs VALUES (1, 1);
SELECT * FROM user_tariffs;
```

**Remark**

Triggers are not the best solution here, in my opinion. Try to avoid triggers, if possible. They can have side effects (transactions etc). Check StackOverflow for further details :)

Comment: I dont understand how it prevents misuse of tariffs for different receptions, could you explain? Ok, index is unique and we have unique row `Putin->Cheap` in users_tariffs, but Cheap is not allowed tariff for Putin's reception...

Comment: Can you add a table with example row data please? Just a few rows to explain the problem further.

Comment: Example is in the question - there is an E.G. block.

Comment: If you don't want to change the table `user_tariffs`, then you can only use trigger. You cannot use `CHECK (other table)` on other tables, only on the table you are in and only on one row. This is why i propose to change the table `user_tariffs` and `ADD COLUMN reception` to it. Trigger can be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks! It is sooo complicated at the end...wow. Thanks for you solutions, but I'd better put resrictions and check in update function in the php model. It wont protect me from addition of row by hands, but trigger looks even worse.

Comment: If you do it in the application, then you need to watch for changes in three tables: `users, tariffs and user_tariffs`. `user_tariffs` for insert and update. But also for UPDATEs in the `users` table, for which you need to RECHECK all many-to-many relationships `(user_id, tariff_id)`, if a `users.user_id` changes its `reception`. Also, if you cache rows of tables in your app, the caches need to be kept up-to-date. If you have multiple apps running concurrently, watch for read-write race conditions. Ask me how i know to be careful :)

Comment: Also consider that your app crashes at any time. Also, assume two concurrent apps, with one changing the users table and the other changing tariffs. I think, they need to happen sequentially, one after the other. Consider transaction isolation SERIALIZABLE. And deal with serialization failure by retrying. Because your app can crash at any time, RECHECK and UPDATE should go into a transaction. Also RECHECK and UPDATE in which order of events? Recheck, when valid then update? Or update, check, and if invalid then rollback?